What to do with a tenuto pizzicato note?
This excerpt from the violin part for "Strike That Reverse It" from the musical Charlie and the Chocolate Factory has a tenuto on a pizzicato note:

I can think of a few possible explanations:

A longer pizzicato articulation is intended. I could imagine theoretically creating a contrast by immediately muting the staccato notes and not the tenuto note, but this seems excessively difficult at tempo.
The orchestrator didn't consider the articulation being pizzicato when adding the tenuto. For example, pizzicato may have been added after the fact without a careful check. In the Broadway cast recording I think a trumpet plays the same run, so the articulations could have been copied into the violin part.
The tenuto is meant to convey emphasis (like a light accent or slightly louder dynamic), with the note still a staccato pizzicato. In this case why would the staccato marking have been omitted?

Have I overlooked anything? What would you do with this notation?

Whenever you have a director of any kind, this is a question for them.

@ToddWilcox The way most musical parts are written, if you asked the director about every little thing like this you'd never get any rehearsing done.

@PiedPiper That’s not been my experience at all. Especially in MT pits, there’s not as many musicians, so it’s not like an entire band asking for interpretation. The other way to go is play it your favorite way and see if the director corrects you. Kinda six of one, half-dozen of the other. The point remains that they will be the final arbiters. Whatever we say here doesn’t matter if the director wants it differently.

Yep, I'll consider bringing this up with the director. I get what PiedPiper is saying though. In my experience with community theatre there are often bigger fish to fry almost right up to performance time.

The articulation might be a mistake, but it's more probable that other instruments (e.g. woodwinds/keyboards) have the same articulation, and the orchestrator has copied it without thinking. The fact that the orchestrator has written superfluous staccato dots over the pizzicato eighths would tend to confirm this. You can't play that note longer but it's unlikely to be noticeable in context.
Musical theater scores are often written to a deadline and there is often lots of illogical/impossible stuff like this. You just have to do the best you can.

The tenuto marking must be a mistake:

The note just after the one marked tenuto is on the beat and the crescendo leads until that top note. The phrase is therefore going one note beyond the one marked tenuto. This indicates the b flat should be used to carry the phrase to the c, and speaks against emphasising it with the articulation.
There is nothing otherwise special about the b flat.
The tempo is too high for such nuances in the articulation. Even if you practice your ass off to do it somehow, literally no one will hear it.
As you noted, in pizzicato it is not obvious how it should be realised.

As a side note, the lyrics start with

Our schedule has no room for intros
Languid and rubato
Accelerate right to the verse
And play it molto presto and staccato!

(Emphasis mine)
Granted, the lyrics do not necessarily dictate notational decisions, but in this case it does speak to the character of the piece and definitely against fiddly unusual articulation details.
If anything, the tenuto could have been intended on the last note of the bar, the goal of the phrase. The c is written as a quarter note, rather than an eighth with a rest, so I could imagine the intention being to direct the player to land on that note rather than overly shortening it. But then we would have to presume the editor not only mistakenly carried over the articulations from another hypothetical part that is not playing pizzicato, but also misplaced the tenuto.
What would I do with this notation? Ignore blissfully.

Agree, unless the director says something I'll ignore the tenuto. It's definitely not meant for the C since other parts are staccato there and there's an eighth pickup right after it. I like that lyric, especially since the intro there is marked as rubato!
